# Angular 5: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403

Tags: java, spring, cors, angular5, http-status-code-403

When I send a POST request to the server I get an error:

```
Failed to load http://localhost:8181/test: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.
```

The backend is written in Java Spring.
My method for creating a test:

```
createTest() {
    const body = JSON.stringify({
      'description': 'grtogjoritjhio',
      'passingTime': 30,
      'title': 'hoijyhoit'
    });

    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
      )
    };

    return this._http.post(`${this._config.API_URLS.test}`, body, httpOptions)
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res );
      }, error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

Get Method works, but Post doesn't. They both work in Swagger and Postman. I changed POST method many times. The headers in my code do not work, but I solved the problem with them expanding to Google Chrome. There was only an error:

```
Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403.
```

It seems to me that this is not Angular problem. Please tell me how I or my friend (who wrote the backend) can solve this problem.

Comment: Can you share the chrome network tab complete details here as that will help to see that the appropriate headers are coming or not?

Answer (score 6):

**PROBLEM :**

For any Cross-Origin POST request, the browser will first try to do a OPTIONS call and if and only if that call is successful, it will do the real POST call. But in your case, the OPTIONS call fails because there is no  `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` response header. And hence the actual call will not be done.

**SLOUTION :**

So for this to work you need to add CORS Configuration on the server side to set the appropriate headers needed for the Cross-Origin request like :

- `response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");`
- `response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "content-type, if-none-match");`
- `response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST,GET,OPTIONS");`
- `response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");`
- `response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");`

Comment: I don't know why this dog byte me so many times. And yet I always forget that is "IN THE RESPONSE" headers where you set the CORS attributes. If you do on the "REQUEST" headers you will continue having problems...

Comment: Happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 3):

You need to ensure that the Spring accept CORS requests

Also if you have applied Spring security & require authorization headers for example for your API, then **(only if you need to make your app support CORS)** you should exclude the OPTIONS calls from authorization in your spring security configuration file.

It will be something like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

  @Override
  public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    // Allow OPTIONS calls to be accessed without authentication
    web.ignoring()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/**")
```

Note:

In production, probably it is better to use reverse proxy (like nginx) & not allow the browsers to call your API directly, in that case, you don't need to allow the OPTIONS calls as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the exact same problem with Angular lately. It happens because some requests are triggering preflight requests eg. `PATCH`, `DELETE`, `OPTIONS` etc. This is a security feature in web browsers. It works from Swagger and Postman simply because they don't implement such a feature. To enable CORS requests in Spring you have to create a bean that returns `WebMvcConfigurer` object. Don't forget of `@Configuration` in case you made an extra class for this.

```
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE").allowedOrigins("*")
                        .allowedHeaders("*");
            }
        };
    }
```

Of course, you can tune this up to your needs.