# Hi! I have a problem with spring-security+angular authentication

Tags: java, angular, spring, typescript, spring-boot

Like in the topic, I have a problem with my spring security + angular application. When I click the authentication button, even when I entered the correct data, I see in the console:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/basicauth'
>   from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It
>   does not have HTTP ok status.

And

> GET http://localhost:8080/api/v1/basicauth net::ERR_FAILED

This is my code in angular:

auth.service.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthenticationService {

  // BASE_PATH: 'http://localhost:8080'
  USER_NAME_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME = 'authenticatedUser'

  public username: String;
  public password: String;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

  }

  authenticationService(username: String, password: String) {
    return this.http.get(`http://localhost:8080/api/v1/basicauth`,
      { headers: { authorization: this.createBasicAuthToken(username, password) } }).pipe(map((res) => {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.registerSuccessfulLogin(username, password);
      }));
  }

  createBasicAuthToken(username: String, password: String) {
    return 'Basic ' + window.btoa(username + ":" + password)
  }

  registerSuccessfulLogin(username, password) {
    sessionStorage.setItem(this.USER_NAME_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, username)
  }

  logout() {
    sessionStorage.removeItem(this.USER_NAME_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME);
    this.username = null;
    this.password = null;
  }

  isUserLoggedIn() {
    let user = sessionStorage.getItem(this.USER_NAME_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME)
    if (user === null) return false
    return true
  }

  getLoggedInUserName() {
    let user = sessionStorage.getItem(this.USER_NAME_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME)
    if (user === null) return ''
    return user
  }
}
```

login.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthenticationService } from './auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  username: string;
  password : string;
  errorMessage = 'Invalid Credentials';
  successMessage: string;
  invalidLogin = false;
  loginSuccess = false;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  handleLogin() {
    this.authenticationService.authenticationService(this.username, this.password).subscribe((result)=> {
      this.invalidLogin = false;
      this.loginSuccess = true;
      this.successMessage = 'Login Successful.';
      this.router.navigate(['/products']);
    }, () => {
      console.log(this.username);
      console.log(this.password);
      this.invalidLogin = true;
      this.loginSuccess = false;
    });      
  }
}
```

http.service.ts

```
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthenticationService } from './login/auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class HttpInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) { }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        if (this.authenticationService.isUserLoggedIn() && req.url.indexOf('basicauth') === -1) {
            const authReq = req.clone({
                headers: new HttpHeaders({
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': `Basic ${window.btoa(this.authenticationService.username + ":" + this.authenticationService.password)}`
                })
            });
            return next.handle(authReq);
        } else {
            return next.handle(req);
        }
    }
}
```

login.component.html

```
<div class="container col-lg-6">
  <h1 class="text-center">Login</h1>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <form class="form-group">
        <div class="alert alert-warning" *ngIf='invalidLogin'>{{errorMessage}}</div>
        <div class="alert alert-success" *ngIf='loginSuccess'>{{successMessage}}</div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email">User Name :</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" [(ngModel)]="username" placeholder="Enter User Name"
            name="username">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter password"
            name="password">
        </div>
        <button (click)=handleLogin() class="btn btn-success">Login</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my code in java:

```
package com.shop.shop.security;

import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception{
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }

}
```

```
package com.shop.shop.security;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1")
public class BasicAuthController {

    @GetMapping(path = "/basicauth")
    public AuthenticationBean basicauth(){
        return new AuthenticationBean("You are authenticated!");
    }

}
```

```
package com.shop.shop.security;

public class AuthenticationBean {

    private String message;

    public AuthenticationBean(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("HelloWorldBean [message=%s]", message);
    }
}
```

Can you help me fix and understand that kind of problem? Thanks! :)

Comment: maybe this will help https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.x/reference/html/cors.html. Basically you need to have response header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" with value "*"'

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49801424/angular-5-response-for-preflight-has-invalid-http-status-code-403 might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is about CORS and you should add something like this:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    System.out.println("CORSFilter HTTP Request: " + request.getMethod());

    // Authorize (allow) all domains to consume the content
    ((HttpServletResponse) servletResponse).addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    ((HttpServletResponse) servletResponse).addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","GET, OPTIONS, HEAD, PUT, POST");

    HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

    // For HTTP OPTIONS verb/method reply with ACCEPTED status code -- per CORS handshake
    if (request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
        resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_ACCEPTED);
        return;
    }

    // pass the request along the filter chain
    chain.doFilter(request, servletResponse);
}
```