# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource, CORS issue

Tags: java, angular, spring, eclipse, spring-security

My code and question are exactly [**This**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58347864/hi-i-have-a-problem-with-spring-securityangular-authentication/58347913#58347913).

But I am getting the error like

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/basicauth' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
zone-evergreen.js:2828 

GET http://localhost:8080/api/v1/basicauth net::ERR_FAILED
```

I have followed the same instruction in the accepted answer still I am getting the same error.

I have added the doFilter method in my `SpringSecurityConfig`  class. Still, I am getting the same error.
I am getting the below error in the network.

> http://localhost:8080/api/v1/basicauth if I hit this URL I am getting 404 error

from eclipse I am running debug mode, it is not showing any debug point enables,
what might be the issue.

[image]
Can you help me fix and understand that kind of problem? Thanks! :)

Comment: OK, what happens when you open http://localhost:8080/api/v1/basicauth directly in your browser?

Comment: I am getting 404 error

Comment: OK, yeah — so you don’t actually have a CORS problem. Instead you have a 404 problem. If you fix the 404 problem, then I expect you’re gonna find that your existing CORS config is already working as expected. You’re seeing that CORS message only because most servers by default don’t add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header to 4xx errors.